# Trigger jQuery function only when in viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, triggers

I have this simple jQuery Counter on my website. The only issue I face, that the counter starts or even has finished before you get to the section where the html code is embedded.

Any help is much appreciated!

```js
<script> 
 var isInViewport = function(elem) {
 var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
 return (distance.top >= 0 && distance.left >= 0 && distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}
// then in your code ..
 if(isInViewPort) {
 $.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            start:  0,
            end:    100,
            easing: 'swing',
            duration: 400,
            complete: ''
        }, options );

        var thisElement = $(this);

        $({count: settings.start}).animate({count: settings.end}, {
            duration: settings.duration,
            easing: settings.easing,
            step: function() {
                var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
                thisElement.text(mathCount);
            },
            complete: settings.complete
        });
    };
$('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 52,duration: 5000});
$('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 35,duration: 3000});
$('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 998,duration: 6000});
}</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this

Vanilla JS: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/
jQuery plugin: https://github.com/zeusdeux/isInViewport

*Updated*  Vanilla version as pseudoCode for directional purposes - Can be optimized tremendously.

```
 var isInViewport = function(elem) {
 var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
 return (distance.top >= 0 && distance.left >= 0 && distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth));
}



 $.fn.jQuerySimpleCounter = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            start:  0,
            end:    100,
            easing: 'swing',
            duration: 400,
            complete: ''
        }, options );

        var thisElement = $(this);

        $({count: settings.start}).animate({count: settings.end}, {
            duration: settings.duration,
            easing: settings.easing,
            step: function() {
                var mathCount = Math.ceil(this.count);
                thisElement.text(mathCount);
            },
            complete: settings.complete
        });
 }

        
 function startCounters() { 
 if(isInViewport($('#number1').get(0))) $('#number1').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 52,duration: 5000});
 if(isInViewport($('#number2').get(0))) $('#number2').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 52,duration: 5000});
 if(isInViewport($('#number3').get(0))) $('#number3').jQuerySimpleCounter({end: 52,duration: 5000});
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    startCounters() 
})
$(window).on("scroll",function(){
startCounters()
})
```

You can improve it with the following updates
1.Instead of the selectors `#number1, #number2` etc. just use a class so your code is cleaner, imagine a future of `#number99`.
2. Should the counter stall at where it was last left or reset?

Comment: Hi Ramakay, thanks for your answer!  Sry, I'm a bit slow today. I can't figure out how to put this all together? 

// This is the code from vanilla JS, but how can I link it to my script? //

var isInViewport = function (elem) {
 var distance = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
 return (
  distance.top >= 0 &&
  distance.left >= 0 &&
  distance.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) &&
  distance.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth)
 );
};

Comment: Updated answer from a direction perspective.

Comment: Thank you so much, Ramakay! I updated the code in my initial question. Would you mind to do a last check?

Comment: Looks good to me, if it doesn't work - you could put in a MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example stripping of any non-shareable code in a site like JSFiddle.  Best of Luck!

Comment: You're gold for your help! Unfortunately I can't get it to work :( 
This is my fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/eg74ua32/

Comment: @muniC - `isInViewPort` is a function, so its my bad - i revised the code. However there needs to be more work done, i have posted the code below as an example, it can be improved much much more and cleaned up - Hopefully it provides you the direction - It triggers the top 2 counters but you have to see why the 3rd one doesn't trigger, treat this as one  approach and expand on it - . https://jsfiddle.net/9asbdxky/46/

Comment: See the updated code and https://jsfiddle.net/52x0uyjp/18/ - Takes care of what you need :) - Is that what you were going for?

Comment: This is great, Ramakay! Please allow me one more question :) 
It works all like it should be: //website loads - you scroll down - counter starts - perfect// 
But when you scroll again - the counter resets and starts again - How can I stop it from doing that?

Comment: looks like that plugin provides a start option, you will have to store them when they go off the viewport and set the initial counter to their last counter number. start will either be zero or the last counter number when `isInViewPort()` was false.

`jQuerySimpleCounter({start:<>,end: 52,duration: 5000})`

Comment: Fist of all, thank you for your patience. Learned a lot so far :) 
Would you mind to show me how you would insert the code to stall the counter above?
I just tried it with //  } else { // but then the counter doesn't fire up anymore -frustrating